# syntax coloring for in house language in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

i am using a in-house scripting language,is there a simple way to highlight all the keywords in eclipse.some editor can just pass keywords XML file in then do the highlight. but i want eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eclipsecolorer
this eclipseplugin can do color.